# How to check validity of a shared pointer in a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why checking the validity of root results in segmentation fault and what is the correct way of checking if the pointer is null?

```
class Node {  
public:
  int key, value;
  std::shared_ptr<Node> right, left;
  Node(int key, int value) : key(key), value(value) {
    right = nullptr;
    left = nullptr;
  }
};

class BST {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Node> root = nullptr;
public:
  void addElement(int key, int value) {  
    if (root) {
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<BST> bst;
  bst->addElement(10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Just say `if( root )`

Comment: Thank you @Slava for your comment. I have tried that. It fails. `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I am compiling on Ubuntu 16.04: `g++ -std=c++11 bst.cpp && ./a.out`

Comment: That is the better way to check but nothing to do with segfault you get. For seqgfault you most probably have UB in code not shown, that is why [mcve] is required, it is not related if you check it comparing `nullptr` or not

Comment: @user4581301, Exactly. I want the first case to work. However, it fails which seems very unreasonable.

Comment: In the second case `root` is local to the function. You don't show the code that calls `addElement`. My guess is that is where your problem is.

Comment: @mmotamedi144 your code works fine if I fill in the code you have not shown. Perhaps the issue is rather in the code you have not shown. Please provide a minimal test case that people can run and observe the same segfault that you get.

Comment: I assume that you invoke UB before.

Comment: @Slava, You are right. I added a minimal, complete version of the code. Thank you.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<BST> bst;` does not allocate a `BST`, just a pointer to one. You need something more like `std::shared_ptr<BST> bst = std::make_shared<BST>();`

Comment: That said, it's questionable whether you need a shared pointer to the `BST`. You don't in this example, which admittedly is trivial, but even in a larger program do you really have multiple owners of the `BST`?  If you do, do you really need multiple owners? If you do need them, you may have a design flaw.

Comment: Another side note, this is a BST without any parent tracking.. There will be no cycles, or other nastiness with nodes pointing at nodes that have been pointed at by other nodes.You should consider implementing with `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to create an instance of your BST class in main(),

```
bst->addElement(10, 10);
```

calls `addElement` on a null pointer, that's where the segfault comes from. Instead do

```
auto bst = std::make_shared<BST>();
bst->addElement(10, 10);
```